# I can't figure out why my UserModel gives an error in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to get Oauth2 to work with CodeIgniter, but I keep running into a 500 error when trying to post request with Postman.

I've found that if I comment out the instantiation of the new UserModel, the error quits happening.

User.php(Controller):

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use \App\Libraries\Oauth;
use \OAuth2\Request;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Models\UserModel;


class User extends BaseController
{
    use ResponseTrait;

    public function login(){
        $oauth = new Oauth();
        $request = new Request();
        $respond = $oauth->server->handleTokenRequest($request->createFromGlobals());
        $code = $respond->getStatusCode();
        $body = $respond->getResponseBody();
        return $this->respond(json_decode($body), $code);
       
    }

    public function register(){
        helper('form');
        $data = [];

        if($this->request->getMethod() != 'post')
            return $this->fail('Only post request is allowed');

        
           
        $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();

        
        
        $rules = array(
            'firstname' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
            'lastname' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
            'email' => 'required|valid_email',
            //'email' => 'is_unique[users.email]',
            'password' => 'required|min_length[8]',
            'password_confirm' => 'matches[password]',
        );
  
        if(!$this->validate($rules)){
            return $this->respond($validation->getErrors());
            
        }else{ 
            
            $model = new UserModel();
            
            $data = [
            'firstname' => $this->request->getVar('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $this->request->getVar('lastname'),
            'email' => $this->request->getVar('email'),
            'password' => $this->request->getVar('password'),
            ];
 
            
            $user_id = $model->insert($data);
            $data['id'] = $user_id;
            unset($data['password']);
            

            return $this->respondCreated($data);
           
        }
    }
}
```

UserModel.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model{
    
  protected $table = 'users';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';
  protected $allowedFields = ['firstname','lastname','password','email'];
  
  protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
  protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];

  
  protected function beforeInsert(array $data){
    $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
    return $data;
  }

  protected function beforeUpdate(array $data){
    $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
    return $data;
  }


  protected function passwordHash(array $data){
    if(isset($data['data']['password']))
      $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    return $data;
  }

}
```

I don't know if the problem goes into the Oauth stuff, but if it does, please let me know and I can provide other code.

Such as Oauth.php from the login() function:

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries;

//use \OAuth2\Storage\Pdo;
use \App\Libraries\CustomOauthStorage;


class Oauth{
  var $server;

  function __construct(){
    $this->init();
  }

  public function init(){
    $dsn = getenv('database.default.DSN');
    $username = getenv('database.default.username');
    $password = getenv('database.default.password');

    $storage = new CustomOauthStorage(['dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
    $this->server = new \OAuth2\Server($storage);
    $this->server->addGrantType(new \OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials($storage));
  }
}
```

This code is producing a server 500 error when posting in Postman. The request works when I comment out UserModel instantiation. And while I'm on this subject, would anyone happen to know why I have to comment out the password verification line in the User.php rules array in order to get that to work?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check your web servers error log to find the real error message.

Comment: I may be looking at the wrong logs, but all I see is 57113 Accepted, 57114 Accepted, 57113 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection.

Comment: Are you looking at the error log or the access log? You can also make PHP output the errors on screen (if you're working locally). In your php.ini file, make sure that `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL` and that `display_errors` is set to `On` (don't forget to restart the web server if you're using Apache or PHP-FPM if you're on Nginx). CodeIgniter probably have some debug setting as well.

Comment: Another way is to add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the top of the index file. Just don't forget to remove that in production.

Comment: Okay, I found the error logs, but all they say is [Fri Jul 24 22:07:04.477411 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1308] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) PHP/7.3.11 configured -- resuming normal operations, and
[Fri Jul 24 22:07:04.477685 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1308] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I figured it out. The issue was actually in my .env file. I was using the wrong DBDriver. I was incorrectly using PDO, instead of MySQLi.